# What is correct syntax for below MYSQL Query IN CI?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, mysqli

My Version is :

```
    $this->db->select('cam_id') ->where('cam_id NOT IN (SELECT cam_id FROM bus) AND cam_id %2 != 0') ->order_by("cam_id","asc") ->limit(1) ->get('camera') ->row_array();
```

But got error : CI convert it like

```
SELECT `cam_id` FROM `camera` WHERE `cam_id` NOT IN (SELECT `cam_id` FROM `bus`) AND `cam_id` `%2` !=0 ORDER BY `cam_id` ASC LIMIT 1;
```

put commas ***Around %2*** which is wrong syntax and without commas this query works perfect

[image: Result of MYSQL Query]

Comment: When creating complex queries (like you are using a subquery), then it's better just to put your entire SQL inside $this->db->query();

Comment: `cam_id % 2 != 0` is performing a modulo on cam_id, so unsure as to why it is wrapped in quote identifiers.